# Better paradigms for posting JSON from a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

With a table based interface where users can update the rows by pressing a button. Perhaps there is a better way of doing this, without pressing a button, i.e. post on textarea/row change (could be a selectbox column). My requirement is that it's the LEAST amount of JavaScript possible, without being cryptic.

For example, could the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/m2nypxyz/9/) be improved (assume an uptodate Firefox/Chrome browser), ideally without changing the HTML?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('button').click(function () {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    row.css("background-color", "red");
    var id = row.children(':nth-child(1)').text();
    var note = row.find('textarea').val();
    var data = {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            note: note
        })
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        row.css("background-color", "green");
    });
});
});
```

I want less code for the JavaScript and I was thinking how much effort if would be to remove the jQuery dependency entirely. Ashamedly it took me a long time to write that jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $('button').click(function () {
>     var row = $(this).parent().parent();
> ```

The `button` selector is not specific enough. To make sure that `.parent().parent()` will be what you think it is, and to clarify it in the code, I would recommend this way instead:

```
$('tr > td > button').click(function () {
```

---

Having the `id` value as the text of a `td` field is not great. Judging by the name "id", it sounds like technical information that shouldn't really be visible. In HTML5 you can use attributes prefixed with `data-` for embedding technical details invisibly inside your HTML. So I would write your rows this way:

```
<tr data-id="goonies">
    <th>Goonies</th>
    <td>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button>Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And then you could get `id` like this:

```
var id = row.attr('data-id');
```

---

> Perhaps there is a better way of doing this, without pressing a button, i.e. post on textarea/row change (could be a selectbox column).

You *could* trigger your function on a change to the textarea, in addition to the button, for example:

```
function onRowChanged() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    row.css("background-color", "red");
    var id = row.attr('data-id');
    var note = row.find('textarea').val();
    var data = {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            note: note
        })
    };

    // ...
}
$('tr > td > button').click(onRowChanged);
$('tr > td > textarea').change(onRowChanged);
```

---

> I want less code for the JavaScript and I was thinking how much effort if would be to remove the jQuery dependency entirely.

For the record, I don't think there's anything wrong with having some JavaScript code. On the other hand, getting rid of jQuery can be a good thing, if you only need a tiny subset of its power. It's certainly possible to rewrite this small piece of code without jQuery, but I'm not very good at that myself. Instead, I can recommend [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) as an ultra-light jQuery replacement. You can try it in your fiddle, just change the Framework to Zepto, and make a small modification to your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        row.css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
```

---

I hope this helps, but you might want to wait for some *real* JavaScript experts to respond!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Esp Zepto.js. However I didn't see the point of duplicating the id value in data-id. It should be straight forward to lookup X table headed column value in a row imo.

Comment: In principle, it's good to separate internal details from presentation. In `<td>title</td>`, "title" is part of the presentation, but in `<td data-id="title">Title</td>` it is not. Also, looking at just `<td>title</td>`, you cannot tell that's an id with internal significance, but with using `data-id` that's quite clear and natural.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a delegated event handler. The more buttons there are the more optimal it becomes:

```
$('#id_of_table').on("click", "button", function () {
```

---

`$(this).parent().parent();` is quite fragile, should you change the HTML structure. Aside from janos' sugggestion, you should use `$(this).closest("tr")`.

---

Hard-coding the background color change is a bad idea. Just set/remove a class instead and style that class.

---

`row.children(':nth-child(1)')` looks wrong to me. In this case I'd markup the first column as `th`s and use `row.children("th")`.

---

```
}).done(function (d) {
    row.css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Use `.always()` to reset the color (or remove the class as I suggested), in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Now sure how `row.children("th")` finds me the value in the id column?

Comment: It's just about finding the cell. You still get the ID the same way: `row.children("th").text()` instead of `$(this).children(':nth-child(1)').text()` (or better use the data-attribute janos suggests).